# Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError when rendering templates - Phoenix 1.3

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Following [Sending Email with Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/sending-email) documentation. Having an Error

> Phoenix.Template.UndefinedError) Could not render "welcome.html" for MyApp.EmailView, please define a matching clause for render/2 or define a template at "lib/MyApp/web/templates". No templates were compiled for this module

I've got `welcome.html` in `/templates/email` . If i however have `welcome.html` in `/templates`, i don't face the issue.

... and the function with the error

```
 #lib/Myapp/web/email.ex
 defmodule MyApp.Email do
 use Bamboo.Phoenix, view: MyApp.EmailView

 def welcome_text_email(email_address) do
  new_email()
  |> to(email_address)
  |> from("example@example.com")
  |> subject("Welcome!")
  |>  put_html_layout({MyApp.Web.LayoutView, "email.html"})
  |> render("welcome.html",email_address: email_address)
end


#lib/Myapp/web/views/email_view.ex

defmodule MyApp.EmailView do
 use MyApp.Web, :view
end
```

Comment: Could you confirm that you created `MyApp.Web.EmailView` in `web/views/email_view.ex`?

Comment: Assuming you have email_view.ex in place. Does changing `/templates/email/welcome.html` to `/templates/email/welcome.html.eex ` fixing the problem? not actually sure if extension is necessary...

Comment: @Dogbert,  yes I've created that

Comment: @sysashi,doing that still throws same error

Comment: Did you add the :view option as in the example like `use Bamboo.Phoenix, view: MyApp.EmailView`. If that does not  work, can you post your complete email module.

Comment: @StevePallen, Please I've edited my question adding some relevant code

Comment: It could be an issue with your `web/web.ex` file in the `view` section. There is a call to `use Phoenix.View, root: "..."` which should point to your templates folder. Are your other non-email views working? The code in bamboo is pretty simple. you can look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/bamboo/blob/master/lib/bamboo/phoenix.ex for some clues. Without your complete project its pretty tough to trouble shoot.

Comment: @StevePallen, My Non Email views are working. Issue is certainly mine. Would find out where i missed it. Thank you so much for your assistance...

Comment: @user1232968 did you ever figure this out?  I seem to have the issue.

Comment: @TrivialCase, Yes I did. Dogbert's first comment was the fix. Check carefully, I missed it on the first check,